# Controlling ListBox scrolling behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

Chapter 10 of "WPF 4 Unleashed" by Adam Nathan includes this XAML example of controlling `ListBox` scrolling behaviour:

```
<Window x:Class="NathanControllingScrollingBehavior.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
             ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
        ...
    </ListBox>

</Window>
```

There isn't an equivalent C# example in the book. I did some research and found a few roundabout ways to do this. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293236/accessing-the-scrollviewer-of-a-listbox-from-c-sharp#comment13246045_10293236) for two approaches which worked for me. These approaches however, seem kind of hackish. Adjusting these properties is quite simple in XAML, but awkward from C#.

Is this simply an area of WPF which was meant to be used only from XAML and not C#? Can anyone explain the disparity in ease of use of these properties between XAML/C#? Is it just an oversight of the WPF team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

listBox1.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty,
ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);

listBox1.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, 
ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);

listBox1.SetValue(ScrollViewer.CanContentScrollProperty, false);

listBox1.SetValue(ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabledProperty, true);
```

Comment: Thank you Nikhil! This is perfect.