# Image inside a collapsed Tab is hooked before it's container (Grid) load causing a NullReferenceException in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events

**And well yes**, maybe it's the weirdest think you ever hear...

But, after a change of my project's FW version, (from 4.5.1 to 4 and again to 4.5.1), a weird thing happens and is:

**Basically**, I have an image that I'm trying to change its source, that image is inside a DataTemplate, so I have to use FindVisualChild (I have 4 different functions that don't work http://pastebin.com/G3hAUPxa) for trigger that element via code...

**The problem is**, that the element is hooked before its container (a grid inside one of the tab items of a tab control) is loaded. (In other words, that image is hooked before I click on the Tab Item that contains the grid that contains the image)

I don't know why, but before it works well, as you can see there in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198626/accessing-elements-inside-a-datatemplate-in-a-tabitem).

And well, I have evidences of what I'm saying, because, if I handle the container (Grid) load, that is inside of a collapsed tab, it loads with the form, simply using a msgbox.

XAML code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCSettings"
                Height="400"
                Margin="39,54,51,173"
                Background="#00F9F9F9"
                BorderBrush="#00DCDCDC">
        <TabItem x:Name="itemOptions" Header="Opciones de juego">
            <Grid x:Name="gameOptions"
                  Width="719"
                  Height="373"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <TabControl x:Name="tabSettings"
                            Width="699"
                            Margin="10,35"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            MouseLeftButtonUp="tabSettings_Click">
                    <TabItem x:Name="itemControls"
                             Height="50"
                             Margin="0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             Padding="6,1">
                        <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="iconKB"
                                           Width="25"
                                           Height="25"
                                           Stretch="Fill" />
```

VB Code

```
Private Sub GridLoaded() Handles gameOptions.Loaded
    MsgBox("Anything") 'That msgbox is called when the form loads, and before it doesn't happens, as you can see in the other question. 
    'And well, If I put anything here, by some reason it returns a NullReferenceException, and the function (FindVisualChild) is not wrong because yesterday after doing that crazy things it works correctly.
End Sub
```

The function I said in the comments can be found [there](http://pastebin.com/G3hAUPxa) and as you can see in the other question **@Didier** said that those are correct.

So, what can be happen?

Is there any event that handles control show? In WPF, MyBase.Shown not exists, I use .OnContentRendered(e) but not events are aviable for Grids...

So, what can I do?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: `I have to use FindVisualChild` - Not really. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear. **Data** Templates are intended to be used to show **Data**. This is why it's strongly recommended to use **Data** Binding as opposed to a procedural code approach in WPF.

Comment: I made a very unusual solution... http://pastebin.com/H5FfhXjh I never used that method before, I'm new on WPF can you help me with that? Thanks. ;)